# APM-Agent Attach to Jenkins Application returns 403 No Valid Crumb was includes in request

Tags: jenkins, apm, elastic-apm

I have setup Apm-server in ELK server and Apm-agent in which Jenkins is running.

APM Agent cant send data to APM server because of below error

**Command:**

```
java -jar /etc/apmagents/apm-agent-attach-standalone.jar \
    --continuous \
    --config service_name=my-cool-service \
    --config server_url=http://x.x.x.x:8080



2021-03-26 07:30:58,423 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] INFO  co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler - Backing off for 36 seconds (+/-10%)
2021-03-26 07:31:31,238 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] ERROR co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler - Error sending data to APM server: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://x.x.x.x:8080/intake/v2/events, response code is 403
2021-03-26 07:31:31,238 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] WARN  co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler - <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/intake/v2/events</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>403</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>No valid crumb was included in the request</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>Stapler</td></tr>
</table>
```

This is the **jenkins.log** file

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you share the version of both APM server and agent? Also, you didn't attach the jenkins.log file.

Comment: APM server version is 7.x and agent is 1.x..I have attached the jenkins.log please check it